# Playback the output of recorded Audio using javax.sound.sampled

Tags: java, audio

i have a problem verifying the output I´ve captured. My program should capture Audio from a mic and then save it as a WAVE file. It does that, but listening to the file only results in crumbling noises, no actual voice recorded.

My code is this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

import java.io.File;

public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, LineUnavailableException {
    TargetDataLine line = null;
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, getAudioFormat());

    try
    {
        line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(getAudioFormat());
    }
    catch (LineUnavailableException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    line.start();
    AudioInputStream stream = new AudioInputStream(line);

    Stopper stopper = new Stopper(line, stream);
    stopper.start();


    File file = new File("C:/Users/Martin/Documents/soundfile.wav");
    AudioSystem.write(stream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);

    System.out.println("Stopped...");
    System.in.read();
}

public static AudioFormat getAudioFormat()
{
    AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;

    float sampleRate = 8000.0f;
    int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
    int channels = 2;
    int frameSize = 4;
    int frameRate = 8000;
    boolean bigEndian = true;

    return new AudioFormat(encoding,
            sampleRate,
            sampleSizeInBits,
            channels,
            frameSize,
            frameRate,
            bigEndian);
}
```

}

The stopper thread is just this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Stopper extends Thread
{
TargetDataLine line = null;
AudioInputStream stream = null;

public Stopper(TargetDataLine line, AudioInputStream stream)
{
    this.line = line;
    this.stream = stream;
}

public void run()
{
    System.out.println("Press [RETURN] to stop capturing...");

    try
    {
        System.in.read();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {}

    line.stop();
    try
    {
        stream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {}
}
}
```

The Audioformat I´m using is accepted by my mic:

Supported SourceDataLines of default mixer (Mikrofon (Creative SB X-Fi)):

interface TargetDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
  max buffer size:  -1
  min buffer size:  32
  Supported Audio formats:

```
PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
```

Comment: Does the length of the audio clip agree with the length of time you were recording?  If so, my knee jerk reaction is that it's a problem with your audio settings.  I assume you're familiar with the [Java Turorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html) on capturing audio.

Comment: Yes, the length of the file correlates with the length of my recording. I made the code using those tutorials, the strange part is, i get the feeling that the crumbling noises intesify when i touch my mic, giving me the feeling htat its actually targeting the right device but not actually capturing voice

Comment: Actually, what kind of audio settings are you talking about?

Comment: I mean as in the audio settings for you sound card.  Can you (or have you) tried to record audio from the mic from more conventional means?  Crackling noises usually mean that you are getting random electrical interference.  For instance if the input line on your sound card is set to 0 then all you'll pick up is random interference.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's also possible that your `AudioFormat` is not compatible with your sound card (I think this is unlikely if you are following the tutorials).

Comment: I just tried that and it seems you´re right, i can use the mic for Skype and such things, but cant record audio with it (same crackling noises). The mic is set as standard input device though?

Comment: Actually its even weirder: The first few words i say in the first second of the recording are actually fine. If i just go like "lalalalal" for 10 seconds, i can hear the first 3-4 "la" and then its back to crackling noises